# gwt-maven-plugin: webapp structure

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, gwt, war

I am using gwt-maven-plugin and eclipse to create GWT+Spring webapp. In the end I want to get .war file to be deployed to some application server(tomcat etc). The problem is that the generated .war file has strange structure.
[image]

And then I run in on Tomcat the application doesn't work - SimpleGWT.html page has a link to javascript file which does all the job

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="SimpleGWT/SimpleGWT.nocache.js"></script>
```

My guess is that since the SimpleGWT.nocache.js in located inside SimpleGWT folder which is not inside WEB-INF - it is not accessible
Is there any way to alter options of  gwt-maven-plugin in order to get normal webapp structure? Here is part of my pom.xml

```
<!-- GWT Maven Plugin -->
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <!-- Plugin configuration. There are many available options, see 
      gwt-maven-plugin documentation at codehaus.org -->
    <configuration>
        <inplace>true</inplace>
      <runTarget>SimpleGWT.html</runTarget>
      <hostedWebapp>${webappDirectory}</hostedWebapp>
      <i18nMessagesBundle>com.javacodegeeks.gwtspring.client.Messages</i18nMessagesBundle>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "normal webapp structure", your WAR looks good to me. (your `SimpleGWT.html` and `SimpleGWT.css` are not in `WEB-INF` right? so why do you want `SimpleGWT.nocache.js` to be in `WEB-INF`?) What's the exact error/problem you're seeing deploying this WAR file to Tomcat?

Comment: Tomcat does not complain. When SimpleGWT.html get loaded it says that SimpleGWT/SimpleGWT.nocache.js - 404 not found. When I put this script into WEB-INF by manually reassembling war it works

Answer (score 0):

Its the issue that is mostly related to access static resources in an HTML page.

You are using `relative path` that does *not* have a "/" prefix.  That is an absolute path 
pointing to the root of the web-server.

In `Spring MVC` application `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet` is responsible fore serving all the contents for web apps.

What have you defined as `url-pattern` for above servlet mapping? Please try with `*.html` or `/*` as `url-pattern`.

For more information read about [Unable to load java script files in Jetty webapplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15972262/unable-to-load-java-script-files-in-jetty-webapplication?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Comment: Braj, nochace.js is not missing from war. It is inside SimpleGWT folder. But when this war is generated this folder ends up not being inside WEB-INF. So when I run this war on apache tomcat the browser can't download the script because it is not inside WEB-INF. I tried and manually put SimpleGWT folder inside WEB-INF and then app works perfect. However manually reassembling war file seems to me kind of blasphemous )))

Comment: What is the value of `${webappDirectory}`?

Comment: mmm sorry... you mean in maven war plugin? I use eclipse with maven plugin. Inside my pom I don't have war plugin. Maybe I should post my pom.xml?

Comment: I found what I needed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16295347/maven-how-to-copy-sub-folders-and-their-content-in-a-different-structure